# Closed Won Opportunity to shared with abc User

Tags: sharing

I am confused by that scenario.
I want to share `Closed-Won` opportunities with the `ABC`user. Is it possible in salesforce? because if we use sharing rule on a Criteria base, what will be the profile and OWD  for a particular User.
Need your Opinion.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a bit of effort.

First, your OWD for Opportunities must be Private, so that users can't see any arbitrary record. You can never restrict sharing below the OWD, as this is the minimum access level.

Second, the user's profile can be whatever you want, but it must include "Opportunity: Read," or the user can't see any opportunity records at all, and must not have "View All Data" or "Opportunity: View All Data".

The user's Role in the Role Hierarchy must not be above any other users that they shouldn't be able to see, because a manager can always see whatever their subordinates can see.

Depending on your needs, you may need two or more sharing rules: one for this user (a Criteria-Based Sharing Rule), and one or more additional rules so other users can see each other's records per your organization's data sharing specifications.

Comment: Without Role Hierarchy. Is it possible??

Comment: suppose OWD is Private and there is no Role Hierarchy. Profile for Opportunity is  ``Read`` And Sharing rule is criteria base ???

Comment: @Fawadazam That would be fine, too.